# Add column in PowerBI/powerQuery which counts values from other columns in my model

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have 5 columns in my model which I want to use to have a 'count' column enabling me to see how many of these columns are populated by a value.

Or an average to see the average of these columns PER ROW

In excel I would do a =COUNT(RANGE), but is a similar function available in powerBI?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said whether you want a Power Query or DAX solution so I will provide a PQ solution.

In PQ, add a new custom column and paste in the following code:

```
List.NonNullCount(Record.ToList(_))
```

When posting future questions, please post text in a table so it can be easily reused by whoever chooses to answer. Also, I see from your history that you have asked other questions which have received answers but you have not marked them as solutions nor provided feedback to the answer author. It is good etiquette on Stack Overflow to mark a question as solved if it has been correctly answered.